# Process hangs after tests complete successfully

Tags: intern, browserstack

Our tests are all running successfully and completing, and we see the coverage summary & following table with `TOTAL: tested X platforms, 0/X tests failed` however the process then seems to hang.

I had been able to run them using Intern 3.0.3 however since trying a newer version it now seems to hang all the time (even if I specify version 3.0.3)...

I understand there are problems with Browserstack and we have had problems that turned out to be there before, however it's difficult to tell if this would in fact be a Browserstack issue? Is it still with Browserstack after the coverage tables are displayed?

Comment: I am seeing the exact the same thing, tests all pass using the `intern-runner` yet hang after the final line `TOTAL: tested....`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** This has now been addressed with an update to [digdug/BrowserStackTunnel.js](https://github.com/theintern/digdug/blob/master/BrowserStackTunnel.js) and looks like it'll form part of the 1.5.0 DigDug release.

---

I took a look into this, I'm new to Intern and I thought it'd be a good way to learn.

After spending a bit of time tracing through Intern's `Runner` and `Executor` modules I finally landed in the DigDug `Tunnel` module. After adding a few `console.log` here and there I found the line it was hanging on (digdug/Tunnel.js:554):

```
childProcess.kill('SIGINT');
```

This line is responsible for closing the Tunnel (which in my case was to BrowserStack). I was able to get the runner to exit cleanly by simply changing from `SIGINT` to `SIGTERM`.

The question is, why doesn't it work with `SIGINT`? (According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT); it's nearly identical to `SIGTERM`). The original question mentioned issues with BrowserStack (for ref I'm using v5.1 of the [BrowserStackLocal](https://www.browserstack.com/browserstack-local/BrowserStackLocal-darwin-x64.zip) for OS X) so in all likelihood there is still an issue here. But I could see no documentation on the binary.

That said, I noticed on the BrowserStack automate website that all the sessions are closed correctly and the runs are correctly labelled by Intern via the BrowserStack REST API as pass / fail etc. So, could there be something within Intern hanging onto the Tunnel?

Comment: Seems to have made its way into 1.4.0 and Intern 3.1.0. Thanks very much for investigating!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mattjbones is correct. The BrowserStackLocal did not seem to be terminated after sending SIGINT. However, I tried running Intern tests using the new version of the binary (v5.2) they released today and everything works great now! Can you guys try it out?